# How to escape some of the html tags using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a regex in javascript using which I want to formate a html string in such a way that all the html tags with event attributes should get formatted. For example

```
    <img src="image.png" onload="alert(123)">
```

or

```
    <img src="image.png" onerror="alert(123)">
```

should be formatted to

```
<img src="image.png">
```

it should remove all the event attributes only starting with 'on'.

Comment: [Regex at terrible at dealing with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068) and **definitely** not reliable enough to use as an XSS filter.

Comment: What is your expected output from `<b onclick=alert(123)>Qucik brown fox</b>`? Do you want the tag to be removed (ala `.remove()`) or do you want it to be replaced by its contents?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use DOMParser instead: turn the string into a document, then iterate over all elements of the document. If any of their attributes start with `on`, remove the element:

```js
const clean = str => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  for (const elm of doc.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    for (const attrib of elm.attributes) {
      if (attrib.name.startsWith('on')) {
        elm.remove();
      }
    }
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
};
console.log(clean('<b onclick=alert(123)>Qucik brown f</b>'));
console.log(clean('<b>Qucik brown f</b>'));
```

I'm *pretty sure* all inline handlers start with `on` (onclick, onload, on), so that should detect all of them.

(but note that the process doesn't exclude actual `<script>` tags)

Not clear from the question, but if you want the children of such an element to persist, then:

```js
const clean = str => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  for (const elm of doc.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    for (const attrib of elm.attributes) {
      if (attrib.name.startsWith('on')) {
        elm.replaceWith(...elm.childNodes);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
};
console.log(clean('<b onclick=alert(123)>Qucik brown f</b>'));
console.log(clean('<b>Qucik brown f</b>'));
```

Comment: It should remove the tag itself in case JS is present

Comment: Also how you will differentiate that tag has some JS in it ?

Comment: `.remove()`?... I think he wants to keep the content... so *if startsWith than* `elm.replaceWith(...elm.childNodes)`